# Compiling in Debug configuration works fine, but Release gives link errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, glfw

I'm using GLFW (`glfw3.lib`, not `glfw3dll.lib`) and GLAD (`glad.c`) with Visual Studio 2017. Compiling in Debug configuration works fine, while Release builds throw out strange linker errors. These are "unresolved external symbols":

```
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strstr
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_malloc
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler3
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwSwapBuffers
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_exit
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwGetKey
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2@YAPEAX_K@Z)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwTerminate
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwPollEvents
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwInit
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwSetWindowShouldClose
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwCreateWindow
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwWindowHint
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwMakeContextCurrent
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwSetWindowTitle
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwGetProcAddress
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glfwWindowShouldClose
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getenv
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Solutions\Order of the Stone\Order of the Stone\x64\Release\Order of the Stone.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 27 unresolved externals
```

Runtime library option is "Multi-threaded DLL" ("Multi-threaded Debug DLL" for Debug). I'm using the precompiled Windows GLFW binaries. Windows SDK is Windows 10 SDK.

Any help is appreciated.

---

## EDIT

I've checked the include directory for release, turns out it was for the wrong architecture (32 bit instead of 64 bit). But now it gives an another list of unresolved externals:

```
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(input.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strstr
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_malloc
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler3
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_exit
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2@YAPEAX_K@Z)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3@YAXPEAX_K@Z)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getenv
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup
1>glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strstr
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(input.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused
1>glfw3.lib(input.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused
1>glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __chkstk
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(init.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strdup
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strdup
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strdup
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_qsort
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_qsort
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sqrt
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pow
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.c.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strcmp
1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Solutions\Order of the Stone\Order of the Stone\x64\Release\Order of the Stone.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 28 unresolved externals
```

Note that 32 bit Release works fine, it's 64 bit Release build that is having these weird linker errors.

Comment: have you actually added the .libs to the configuration for release mode? You can set the options for each configuration, so I suspect you did for debug, but not for release.

Comment: @Zinki Additional Include Directories are correct, I checked that twice. The actual libraries to be included are specified in a header (`#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")`) which is included in all configurations.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the question, providing more details

Comment: looks like a debug version of glfw3.lib bing linked against a release application

Comment: @AlanBirtles So I should rebuild GLFW from source in Release configuration and then link that to my application?

Comment: yes, you cant use the same static library for debug and release builds, one convention is to add "d" to the end of the debug build to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Since 64-bit GLFW prebuilt Windows binary is `Debug` for some reason, it wasn't able to link, since my app was in `Release`, not providing necessary debug definitions. The solution is either to compile GLFW from source yourself, in a Release configuration, or to not use 64-bit GLFW at all (32-bit binary strangely is `Release`, since I was able to build my app in `x86/Release`). However, I'm not able to practically prove this, because I'm not using GLFW anymore, since it didn't properly suit my needs.